# Embedded Tomcat Would Not Start

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster, jrebel

I got this error when I run Jhipster project on Jrebel. I try to increase my java heap size until to 512m by insert this line to VM Argument on Arguments Tab, but can not solve the error. I want to ask what the cause of error and how to solve it?

> ${jrebel_args}
>
> -Xms512m -Xmx1024m

```
[ERROR] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.ServletContextInitializerLifecycleListener - Error starting Tomcat context: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
Exception in thread "main" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
Exception in thread "process reaper" Exception in thread "process reaper"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem by add -XX:MaxPermSize=512m at VM Arguments (eclipse)

thanks to ZT (zeroturnaround) Support

Answer (score 0):

Running JVM with JRebel will use up to 50% more memory, if it uses more then there is a problem. Just in case please try to double the max limit with -Xmx2048m . This must avoid the OutOfMemoryError . After that you can reduce it when observing the actual memory usage.